# How to I change a .psd format to .jpeg format without photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I took my work home from a photoshop class, not realizing I didn't save my pictures as .jpeg instead i saved them as .psd and I don't have photoshop to change them, is there a way to change a .psd format to .jpeg format without using photoshop? Or is there a way to add a .psd to a powerpoint without photoshop as well?

Comment: Are you using Mac or PC?

Answer (score 3):

I've heard that some free image editing software (particularly Irfanview) can access the flattened raster preview that is usually stored in PSD files (much like the JPG previews that exist in DNG files). I must admit, I've never had to try this myself, but it should be possible to load this flattened image in IrfanView then re-save it as JPG.
More info here:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-best-ways-to-open-a-psd-file-without-photoshop/

Comment: That relies on "Maximize compatibility" having been selected when the PSD was saved, but yes, it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GIMP.

Open the file and then use the File -> Export as... command. Choose the JPEG format that you need.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools available in psd to jpg without photoshop.

GIMP,
paint.net,
psd viewer
Photo Filter
etc.
you can use this tool

Answer (score -1):

Open it with Picassa or OpenOffice and then 'save as' jpg file.

Comment: OpenOffice Draw, or other applications too?

Answer (score -5):

There is no way of converting it without Photoshop AND keeping YOUR photo as YOUR property. Sorry bud.